# set function on a root level is extremely dangerous

Tags: firebase

I have ran a script accidentally which has the set command on the root level and it completely destroyed all data.

```
var Firebase = require('firebase');
var myRootRef = new Firebase('https://myprojectname.firebaseIO-demo.com/');
myRootRef.set("hello world!");
```

I understand there is an 'update' method but I think there should be some configuration or something which prevents it from doing this on the root level.

There is always a chance of using 'set' method by mistake or chance of hacking which can completely destroy the data.

Answer (score 3):

You should make sure to write Security Rules that control access to your data. This will prevent both accidental data corruption and malicious attacks.